# Why do I get an empty cursor sql lite

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I did my own `SQLiteOpenHelper`, and it fills correctly. My problem is that when I try to do a `rawquery` to get the values I need, my cursor is empty. I checked my Database and the Value I'm trying to get exists. So what am I doing wrong?
Here is the code I'm using for `SELECT` query.

```
SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();

String[] params=new String[]{String.valueOf(actd)};

Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ tablename +" WHERE '"+dayStart+"' = ?",params);

Log.d("Cursor State", String.valueOf(cursor.moveToFirst()));
```

Hope you can help me  because I'm stuck here.

Comment: Is it because you have single quotes around "dayStart"?

Comment: Have you tried logging your query string separately to debug?

Comment: @Phillip Fitzsimmons If I remove the single quotes, it doesnt detect the column name:S

Comment: @Estel Can you give me a example of how to make it please?

Comment: WEEEELL problem fixed, I created the BD wrong, I havent put space between column name and type of column:P Single dots removed as Phillip said. thanks for your comments:D

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

after the query.

Note: This method is deprecated but still works. If you want a better implementation, use `CursorLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

You have put invalid quotes around the dayStart param.

```
Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ tablename +" WHERE "+dayStart+ "= ?",params);
```